# Android App Runs in Emulator, But Not Listed In Launcher

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher

I am learning Android and can not get my program to show up in the program listings drawer of my Nexus S emulated device. When I load up the emulator, it does load my program successfully, after hitting "run new configuration". I know there are a ton of threads on this...but from what I can tell I have everything right in my manifest with:

```
  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Also, to be clear the run configuration in Eclipse does run my program successfully. It's just not in the apps menu/drawer of the emulated device to click and run:

```
[2013-03-07 20:14:04 - TodDoList] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-03-07 20:14:04 - TodDoList] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-03-07 20:14:46 - TodDoList] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-03-07 20:14:46 - TodDoList] Uploading TodDoList.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-03-07 20:14:47 - TodDoList] Installing TodDoList.apk...
[2013-03-07 20:15:23 - TodDoList] Success!
[2013-03-07 20:15:23 - TodDoList] Starting activity com.paad.toddolist.ToDoListActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-03-07 20:15:24 - TodDoList] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.paad.toddolist/.ToDoListActivity }
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.paad.toddolist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.paad.toddolist.ToDoListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TodDoList</string>
    <string name="addItemHint">New To Do List</string>
    <string name="addItemContentDescription">New To Do Item</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: what is the value of `@string/app_name`...

Comment: <string name="app_name">TodDoList</string>

Comment: what is Your's class name, i think problem is at your class name. which is not correct at manifestfile

Comment: If the answer posted here would have solved your issue, you may accept the answer or you may write here your own solution so that the others looking for a solution to this issue, may have some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
android:name="com.paad.toddolist.ToDoListActivity"
```

with

```
android:name=".ToDoListActivity"
```